# Obter a largura e altura da janela

Tags: javascript

Queria obter a largura e altura da janela, para que, caso a minha página seja visualizada em diferente resoluções, se posicionar a janela. Porque, com diferentes resoluções, a página ou fica pequena ou grande.

exempo:

```
<svg width="980" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1200 500">
  <rect ry=0 rx=0 x=50 y=20 width=300 height=200 fill=HoneyDew/>
</svg>
```

Esse objeto, não é sempre do mesmo tamanho mudando a posição

Comment: Logo que eu dei a resposta, você adicionou esse trecho do SVG. Assim sendo, não sei se a minha resposta seria válida.

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer isso utilizando apenas o javascript, você pode utilizar as propriedades `innerHeight` e `innerWidth`. Elas vão retornar o tamanho atual da sua janela.

Exemplo:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){

    if (window.innerWidth < 300) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
    }

})
```

Adicionamos o evento `onresize` em `window`. Caso o tamanho atual da janela seja menor que `300px` dentro desse evento (`resize`), ele fará o `body` ter o `background-color` da cor vermelha;e, do contrário, da cor verde.

Também há uma maneira de se fazer isso através das [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia).

Veja um exemplo:

```
window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width:300px)').addListener(function()
{

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'

})
```

Você pode observar que o trecho `screen and (max-width)` parece um pouco com a sintaxe do CSS.

**Nota:** Lembrando que `document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'` é apenas um exemplo, e, no lugar dele, deve ser aplicada a sua operação, de acordo com a necessidade que precisa ao detectar o tamanho da janela.